# How to Hide Disabled Payment methods in Admin Configuration in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to hide all the disabled Payment Methods (Ex:Bank Transfer,Purchase Order,Authorize.net etc) in   **Stores → Configuration → Sales → Payment Methods.**

Comment: if you hide it then there's no way you can re-enable it.

Comment: Sure.There is no need to re-enable it.

Comment: I think you are referring to offline payments , if so, you can simply disable it

Comment: Yes.But i want to disable amazon and Paypal module too

Comment: using module disable command you can actually disable which module you want to remove. for paypal you can disable it with its name `Magento_Paypal` and so on

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood it right, you want to disable **Offline Payment Methods**.
You can simply disable it or uninstall it through CLI, try below commands:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_OfflinePayments
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache"flush
```

Answer (score 2):

For Authorize.net you can simply disable Magento_Authorizenet module or its dependent modules but if you disabled Magento_OfflinePayments (it will disable all payment method like check-money order also). So Before disabling this make sure all offline payment methods are disabled.